# Перестал работать подключённый стиль CSS

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap

Почему после подключения к HTML странице CSS Twitter Bootstrap, перестал работать обычный стиль?

```
<head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />      
</head>
```

Точнее, часть свойств работает, а часть нет.

Допустим, этот блок перестал выполняться правильно:

```
html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #599FD1;
    font-family: Calibri;
}
```

Comment: попробуйте html,body { ваши стиль !important; }
в бутстрапе очень много стилей прописаны с !important, те они получаются главнее ваших, подозреваю что бутстрап версия 2+, попробуйте 3 вроде они там отказались от !important.

Comment: Последовал вашему совету, но всё по-прежнему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего bootstrap просто ваши стили !important -ом перекрывает. Вообщем посмотрите через chrome web tools. Он отлично всё показывает:

[image]

Comment: Подскажите, как быть в таком случае?

Comment: Использовать 3 бутстрап или не использовать его вообще.

Comment: Выше уже предлагали. Подключил папку css из папки dist вроде. То же самое.